# MKV to M2TS muxer for Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, matroska, m2ts

I currently use the tsMuxeR for Windows within a VM on my Mac to mux MKV to M2TS to play on my PS3. tsMuxeR currently doesn't have a version that works with Snow Leopard, and I have not had any luck finding a native Mac application that will run on Snow Leopard that can do what tsMuxeR can.

Does anyone know of a native Mac Snow Leopard application that can mux MKV to M2TS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tsMuxeR has a Mac version. I guess it hasn't been updated to work with Snow Leopard? You can always try running the windows version using Wine. I haven't used Wine on a mac, and I haven't used tsMuxeR on Wine, so I have no idea if this would work, but google search results seem to indicate that it works for at least one person.

Comment: I am sorry I guess I wasn't clear, I already use tsMuxeR in a VM, and tsMuxeR doesn't have a Snow Leopard version and if you use their leopard version it crashes on launch.  I have used Wine in the past and every time I am left disappointed by how far behind it is. Running apps with Wine is not the same as running native, it is more like running with a Windows emulator.  

I am looking for a Mac native application that works with Snow Leopard. I will update the question to include the word native to make that clear.

Comment: FWIW, there is an unofficial version that works with Snow Leopard: http://instantitunes.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/use-tsmuxer-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: I know that running in wine is not the same as running native, but it's certainly better than not running at all, if you can make it work.